# Values stored multiple times into array

Tags: php

I am trying to save values from my database into an array, this works however it shows some of the values multiple times some of them 2 and other ones 3 times.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "testdb");
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM vraag");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// run query
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// set array
$array = array();

// look through query
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

  // add each row returned into an array
  $array[] = $row;

  // OR just echo the data:
  echo $row['vraag']; // etc

}



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnData) {
         echo $columnData;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why do you run your query twice with procedural and OOP style?!

Comment: The OP is also trying to loop through the result set twice instead of using the array they've created.

Comment: delete duplicate code from 5-24 lines. use second `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` instead

Comment: I deleted the duplicate code on lines 5-24 but is till get every value twice, after each other.